# If an airline or immigration policy requires an onward ticket, is it ok to purchase it at the last minute or after being refused check-in/entry?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airlines, proof-of-onward-travel, no-advance-plans

If an airline or immigration policy requires an [onward ticket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onward_ticket), is it allowed or sufficient for airline and immigration policies to purchase it at the last minute or after being refused check-in/entry?

E.g., if the airline's check-in front desk refuses a traveler because of lack of onward tickets, can the traveler buy an onward ticket on their phone and  be right after accepted by the airline's check-in front desk?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNtdCd

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105327/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-if-an-airline-or-immigration-policy). The comments on the question will be locked for a while, please go to the chatroom to discuss this question.

Comment: I don't understand why the question was closed as opinion-based by a couple (between 2 to 4) of individuals. It seems ok to me as the answer is yes, no, or it depends on X/X/Z. I don't see any opinion here. Or do we want to close all questions regarding immigration and airline policy as opinion-based, because from time to time employees fail to respect to their employers' policies?

Comment: I've done this a few times. Was refused at check-in due to lack of proof of onward journey. Bought a ticket on my phone and then reattempted to check-in and succeeded. Maybe this depends on country and airline? If so the question is broad and not opinion-based.

Comment: @JoErNanO I don't know whether this depends on country and airline. That'd be a valid answer. I wish the question wasn't closed so that it could receive answers, even if the answer is it depends on X and Y, at least I'd know x and y.